# How to clone Mongoose schema?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am working on Mongoose plugin that have to access existing model and create similar schema as previous model and fix some attributes and add some custom properties. How to do such cloning of scheme? I tried but its not working:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var mainSchema = new mognoose.schema({'prop' : String});
var anotherSchema = new mongoose.schema(mainSchema);
```

Of course, its not working at all and I can't find any solution in API doc and source code (as far I can read that code).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For anyone googling, try:

```
schema.clone();
```

This creates a full copy of the schema, so you can add more properties, multiple discriminators, etc.

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema-clone

Comment: Thanks. This is the correct way. The properties can then be added using `YourSchema.add()` as [documented here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema-add).

Answer (score 3):

Assign the schema to a regular object first:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var schemaObj = {'prop' : String}
var mainSchema = new mongoose.Schema(schemaObj);
var anotherSchema = new mongoose.Schema(schemaObj);
```

Comment: That is obvious, but unfortunately I can't to do this, regarding to this code works in plugin so its getting `Schema` object as an argument.